# Qt5.2.1 get GPS location on Samsung Galaxy S2Plus (I9105P)

Tags: android, qt

I am trying to get GPS coordinates using Qt5.2.1 on my Samsung Galaxy S2 plus. This is what i tried:

1. Calling QGeoPositionInfoSource::availableSources() always returns an empty list.
2. I tried QGeoPositionInfoSource::createDefaultSource() , also returns NULL pointer.
3. I have set the permissions in AndroidManifest.xml, from QtCreator:

   android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

   android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
4. I also tried with QNmeaPositionInfoSource class, but i have to call setDevice() method for setting a QIODevice, but i don't know where can i get that device. There is any "/dev/bcm_gps" for accessing NMEA GPS coordinates ?

Note: I am trying this on my Samsung Galaxy S2 Plus, with Cyanogenmode11 (Android 4.4.2), Baseband I9105PXXUMBI, Kernel 3.0.101. Other GPS applications works ok, so it's not a Cyanogen bug.

Here are the complete sources. It's just a minimal project for getting GPS coordinates and display them in a textedit. I don't get what i'm doing wrong.

Here is the .pro file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-02-05T15:48:22
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui positioning sql

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = test_position
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY +=

ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android

OTHER_FILES += \
      android/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Here is the main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Here i am trying the Location API:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
     QMainWindow(parent),
     ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setSingleShot(true);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(setupGPS()));
    timer->start(1000);
}

void MainWindow::setupGPS()
{
    QStringList services = QGeoPositionInfoSource::availableSources();

    if (services.isEmpty()) { //services is always empty
        ui->textEdit->setText("positioning sources unavailable");
    timer->start(1000);
    return;
    }

    /**********************************GPS trials***********************************/
    //    ui->textEdit->setText("retry GPS connection");
    source = QGeoPositionInfoSource::createDefaultSource(this);
    if(source){ //never enter here
        ui->textEdit->setText("success");
        source->setPreferredPositioningMethods(QGeoPositionInfoSource::
        AllPositioningMethods);
        connect(source, SIGNAL(positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)),
                this, SLOT(positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)));
        source->startUpdates();
    } else {
        nmeaLocation = new QNmeaPositionInfoSource(QNmeaPositionInfoSource::
        RealTimeMode, this);
        //      ui->textEdit->setText("available sources = " + QString::number(
        nmeaLocation->supportedPositioningMethods()));
        QIODevice* dev = nmeaLocation->device();
        if(dev){
            ui->textEdit->setText("got device");
        }
        else {
            ui->textEdit->setText("failed to get device");
        }
        //        nmeaLocation->setDevice();
        timer->start(1000);
    }
}

void MainWindow::errorPositioning(QGeoPositionInfoSource::Error er){
    ui->textEdit->setText("error = " + QString::number(er));
}

void MainWindow::positionUpdated(const QGeoPositionInfo &info)
{
    QString latitude, longitude;
    latitude.setNum(info.coordinate().latitude());
    longitude.setNum(info.coordinate().longitude());
    ui->textEdit->setText("Position updated: " + latitude + " " + longitude);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include <QtPositioning/QGeoAddress>
#include <QtPositioning/QGeoAreaMonitorInfo>
#include <QtPositioning/QGeoAreaMonitorSource>
#include <QtPositioning/QGeoCircle>
#include <QtPositioning/QGeoCoordinate>
#include <QtPositioning/QGeoLocation>
#include <QtPositioning/QGeoPositionInfoSource>
#include <QtPositioning/QGeoSatelliteInfoSource>
#include <QtPositioning/QNmeaPositionInfoSource>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();

private:
QGeoPositionInfoSource *source;
QTimer* timer;
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
QNmeaPositionInfoSource *nmeaLocation;

private slots:
void setupGPS();
void errorPositioning(QGeoPositionInfoSource::Error er);
void positionUpdated(const QGeoPositionInfo &info);
};
```

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

And here is the Android manifest:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:installLocation="auto" android:versionName="1.0" 
package="org.qtproject.example">
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtApplication">
     <activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity" 
android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize
|smallestScreenSize|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation"
 android:screenOrientation="unspecified">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="-- 
%%INSERT_APP_LIB_NAME%% --"/>
        <meta-data android:resource="@array/qt_sources" 
android:name="android.app.qt_sources_resource_id"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.repository" android:value="default"/>
        <meta-data android:resource="@array/qt_libs" 
android:name="android.app.qt_libs_resource_id"/>
        <meta-data android:resource="@array/bundled_libs" 
android:name="android.app.bundled_libs_resource_id"/>
        <!-- Deploy Qt libs as part of package -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundle_local_qt_libs" android:value="-- 
%%BUNDLE_LOCAL_QT_LIBS%% --"/>
        <meta-data android:resource="@array/bundled_in_lib" 
android:name="android.app.bundled_in_lib_resource_id"/>
        <meta-data android:resource="@array/bundled_in_assets" 
android:name="android.app.bundled_in_assets_resource_id"/>
        <!-- Run with local libs -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.use_local_qt_libs" android:value="-- 
%%USE_LOCAL_QT_LIBS%% --"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.libs_prefix" 
android:value="/data/local/tmp/qt/"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_libs" android:value="-- 
%%INSERT_LOCAL_LIBS%% --"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_jars" android:value="-- 
%%INSERT_LOCAL_JARS%% --"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.static_init_classes" android:value="-- 
%%INSERT_INIT_CLASSES%% --"/>
        <!--  Messages maps -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.ministro_not_found_msg" 
android:value="@string/ministro_not_found_msg"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.ministro_needed_msg" 
android:value="@string/ministro_needed_msg"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.fatal_error_msg" 
android:value="@string/fatal_error_msg"/>
        <!--  Messages maps -->
        <!-- Splash screen -->
        <meta-data android:resource="@layout/splash" 
android:name="android.app.splash_screen"/>
        <!-- Splash screen -->
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="14" android:minSdkVersion="9"/>
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true"/>
<!-- %%INSERT_PERMISSIONS -->
<!-- %%INSERT_FEATURES -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Ok, should i ask a new question there, or is there any way i can move this question ?

Comment: You can use the 'flag' link below your question to flag it for mod attention and (in the flag comment field) ask to have it migrated. It's then up to the mods to decide how it proceeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://www.kdab.com/qt-on-android-episode-1/) (middle of a post), The Qt Positioning module is not yet implemented on Android, alas. It is planned (not guaranteed) for next Qt version, 5.3, which is expected to be released around the end of april 2014 ([Source](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-5.3-release)).

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've been missdirected by this https://qt-project.org/qt5/qt52 which says somwhere at Positioning paragraph: 'The backend functionality (where the data comes from) is plugin-based and can be extended through the APIs. At this point, Qt Positioning has ready-made working backends for all platforms using the NMEA data (text files) and for Linux there is a GeoClue-based backend available.'