# QGeoPositionInfo not working in QCoreApplication

Tags: qt, qobject, qtconsole, qtandroidextras, geopositioning

I'm trying to get the position updates in QCoreApplication, Following is the code i'm trying but i'm getting error as

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo) to QObject::positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)
```

Code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QtCore>


class MyClass : public QObject
{
//    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyClass(QObject *parent = 0)
        : QObject(parent)
    {
        qDebug() << "In class";

        QGeoPositionInfoSource *source = QGeoPositionInfoSource::createDefaultSource(this);
        qDebug() << source;
            connect(source, SIGNAL(positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)),
                    this, SLOT(positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)));
            source->startUpdates();
    }

private slots:
    void positionUpdated(const QGeoPositionInfo &info)
    {
        qDebug() << "Position updated:" << info;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qDebug("Qt running !");

    MyClass *objmyclass = new MyClass;

    return a.exec();
}
```

If i uncomment the Q_OBJECT i get error as:

```
:-1: error: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
```

Comment: First of all you must uncomment Q_OBJECT. Second one  is what is the source variable value? Can you show QGeoPositionInfoSource::createDefaultSource's body?

Comment: If Q_OBJECT is uncommented, i get the error as: :-1: error: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function, QGeoPositionInfoSource *source = QGeoPositionInfoSource::createDefaultSource(this);

Comment: That's ok! Error is in the another place.

Comment: About createDefaultSource from the doc

**Returns 0 if the system has no default position source, no valid plugins could be found or the user does not have the permission to access the current position** Can you comment this function call?

Comment: Permission for location access is been added, this works fine for GUI application, only has this issue with QCoreApplication

Comment: Add #include "main.moc" after the main method! :)
Then run qmake, build and all will be ok

Comment: Thankyou for reply,  but  #include after main() ?

Comment: Yes, after main() {}

Comment: But i get error as main.moc no such file or directory.

Comment: Right mouse click on your project's name -> Clear -> Run qmake

Comment: i have tried running qmake also cleaned the build, but same error as main.moc dosent exists, should that main.moc need to be created first?

Comment: And i'm building this project for Android platform, thought would be important to be mentioned

Comment: qmake must create all Q_OBJECT classes so your main.moc must be created autimatically by it. I've run your code and it works. Try manually clear the working directory

Comment: Thankyou very much, that solved the issue but, now getting weird error as,  W/        (22093): (null):0 ((null)): QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo) to MyClass::positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)
F/libc    (22093): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 22110 (mycompany.test1)


"com.mycompany.test1" died.

Comment: Can you please help me with that?

Comment: It seems to me the error with **createDeafultSource** it returns 0

Comment: Its returning 0 here in QCoreApplication, works fine with QApplication, does QGeoPositionInfoSouce not works with QCoreApplication?

Comment: And you need QCoreApplication only?

Comment: Actually the application is running as background service on Android, so needed to have QCoreApplication

Comment: Try get available sources with **QStringList QGeoPositionInfoSource::availableSources()** and if it's not empty create source variable by QGeoPositionInfoSource::createSource(availableSources[0])

Comment: The available sources list is empty

Comment: What is your Qt version and may be it helps [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604569/qt5-2-1-get-gps-location-on-samsung-galaxy-s2plus-i9105p)

Comment: its Qt 5.4.1, checked the link but i'm using 5.4.1

Comment: Temporary replace QCoreApplication with QApplication and check again availableSources

Comment: Temporary changing the QCoreApplication to QApplication caused this error and application crashed, F/        (30850): (null):0 ((null)): This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "android".
F/        (30850): 
F/        (30850): Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
F/libc    (30850): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 30869 (mycompany.test1)

Comment: Ok. So turn it back into core and solve the issue with empty available sources

Comment: If i do it with empty sources i get error, D/        (28435): (null):0 ((null)): Available Sources:  ()
W/        (28435): (null):0 ((null)): QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo) to MyClass::positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)
F/libc    (28435): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 28454 (mycompany.test1)


"com.mycompany.test1" died.

Comment: That's all I can help [availableSources is empty](http://www.google.ru/search?q=QGeoPositionInfoSource%3A%3AavailableSources+is+empty&newwindow=1&oq=QGeoPositionInfoSource%3A%3AavailableSources+is+empty&gs_l=mobile-heirloom-serp.12...2473.6415.0.7378.11.10.0.1.1.0.170.664.9j1.10.0....0...1c.1j2.34.mobile-heirloom-serp..10.1.100.7EqdnyHzKb4)

Comment: Thankyou for your help, will see the provided link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Putting class declaration in .cpp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657528/putting-class-declaration-in-cpp-file)